# Converting an integer to a string, through an object

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter

I'm pretty new to XAML and WPF, and I'm trying to build a Converter, which converts an integer to a month (string)
I know the code below doesn't work because it gets an object rather than a string to process, but I have no idea how to handle this object?

```
  public class NumberToMonthConverter : IValueConverter
    {   
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
  object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {                
            if (value is int)
            {
                string strMonthName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(value);
                return strMonthName;
            }   
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close, just cast `value` to `int` after you checked it is an `int`:

```
if (value is int)
{
    return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName((int)value);
}
else // you need this since you need to return a value
{    // throw an exception if the value is unexpected
    throw new ArgumentException("value is not an int", "value");
}
```

Comment: And there should be an else to the check or it won't compile since not all paths return a value.

Comment: I was just quoting (well, misquoting) the c# compiler error message. I'd probably go with an exception too.

Answer (score 0):

why dont use TryParse?

```
int i;
if (int.TryParse(value, out i)) {
            string strMonthName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(i);
            return strMonthName;
}
else  {
    throw new Exception("value is not int!");
    --OR--
    return "Jan"; //For example
}
```